# Series of Witt vectors converges if every series of the components converge

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a perfect field of characteristic $p$, with $p>0$, which is complete with respect to a non-archimedean absolute value (in particular, elements of $\mathbb{F}_p$ have absolute value 0 or 1). Let $W$ be the associated ring of Witt vectors. We know $W$ is complete with respect to the $p$-adic topology and that every element of $W$ can be written uniquely as
$$x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\chi(x_i)p^i$$
where $\chi:K\to W$ is the Teichmuller character and $x_i\in k$ for every $i$. This also allows to see $W$ as the ring $K^{\mathbb{N}}$ via the identification $x\to (x_0,x_1^p,x_2^{p^2},\ldots,)$, but where addition and multiplication are not componentwise, instead they respect the rules given by Witt polynomials. From now on, I will always work in this second setting.

My question is the following: consider a series of elements of $W$ of the form
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}w_j = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(w_{i,j})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}.$$
**Is it true that the convergence in $K$ of the series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}w_{i,j}$ for every $i$ yields convergence of the series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}w_j$ in $W$?**

It is immediate to see that the 0-component of the series is equal to $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}w_{0,j}$. The 1-component is sufficiently simple to guarantee that it is given by $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}w_{1,j}$ minus a series with terms of the form $b\cdot(w_{0,0}+\cdots+w_{0,n})^{a/p}\cdot w_{0,n+1}^{(p-a)/p}$, where $1\leq a\leq p-1$ and $b\in\mathbb{F}_p$. I expect that a similar behavior occurs in every other component, but the Witt relations seem to become too complicated to give an explicit expression like the previous ones.

Concluding, does anyone know if this claim is true? Is there any precise reference for this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it help to say that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty w_j$ is convergent if and only if $\lim_jw_j=0$?

Comment: It would surely help if $\lim_j w_{i,j}=0$ for every $i$ (in the topology of $K$) implies $\lim_j w_j=0$ in the topology of $W$. I think I am missing why this should be true.

Comment: If $W$ has the $p$-adic topology, this is certainly not true as soon as the topology of $K$ is not just the discrete topology. That's the reason one introduces a different "weak" topology on certain Witt vectors in the construction of Fontaine's period rings and $(\varphi, \Gamma)$-modules. Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2938350/96384

Comment: Notice that convergence of a sequence in $W$ w.r.t. the $p$-adic topology means that each "coordinate sequence" is eventually *constant*. (Convergence to $0$ means each coordinate is, after finitely many steps, constant $0$.)

Comment: If I understood correctly, the weak topology is defined exactly in order to imply the convergence of similar series, since a term goes to zero if and only if the number of its coordinates which are small with respect to the absolute value of $K$ increases.
And $W$ is still complete with respect to this topology, so that I really obtain a Witt vector as a result. Am I right?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Just a minor (crucial) correction: Convergence to $u\neq0$ means each coordinate is eventually constant. However, this does not hold for $u=0$.

Comment: F.Battistoni: Sounds right. @Chilote: Maybe I'm overlooking something, but I do not see why there would be anything different for $0$ here.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Just consider the (never constant) null sequence $(p^n)_n$.

Comment: @Chilote: But when considered as Witt vectors, that sequence is $(1,0,0,0,...),(0,1,0,0,...),(0,0,1,0,...),...$. Each coordinate sequence takes constant value $0$ after the single time it has value $1$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg got it, my bad.